# How to get the variable from a perl script that is called within a perl script?

Tags: perl, export, environment-variables

I have two perl scripts **a.pl** and **b.pl**

Within **a.pl**, it calls **b.pl** by `system("/usr/bin/perl ./b.pl");`

Within **b.pl** it will do something and then assign some values to `$aa` and `$bb`

Now in **a.pl** after it calls **b.pl**, **a.pl** needs the values of `$aa` and `$bb` from **b.pl**.

I did research and found people saying to use 'Exporter' or set `$aa` and `$bb` to be `$ENV` in **b.pl**

However after some trials I failed to accomplish it.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call it via `system`, you're calling a subprocess.  You can't get anything out of it that isn't through a pipe (such as stdout).

What you probably want is to `do './b.pl`; instead.  Better yet, put b.pl into b.pm, set its package, and then you can `require b;` and access its globals through its package.

Answer (score 1):

If you for whatever reason need to do this as two application and not to `do`, `use` or `require` another perl script in the application, then you can print results from **b.pl** to STDOUT

```
print join('|', $aa, $bb);
```

and then in **a.pl** read it and split it

```
my ($aa, $bb) = split(/\|/, `/usr/bin/perl ./b.pl`);
```

In case your `$aa` or `$bb` may contain character `|`, choose different separator.

Answer (score 0):

If the b.pl is written without locally declared variables (so no use warning, use strict, no my $aa), you could read the file into a variable and eval it. Otherwise, this won't be possible without modifying b.pl. A few things that are possible:

- Use ENV (as hinted before)
- Print $aa and $bb on STDOUT before the exit of b.pl, read those in a.pl
- Use some well-known [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) method (pipes, sockets, tempfile)
- Move the logic of b.pl to some seperate module, include that module from b.pl and a.pl